# Show that polar of the unit ball is the unit ball of the dual space

Tags: convex-analysis, dual-spaces

I know the definition of the polar set is:
$$C^0 = \left\{ y \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid y^Tx \leq 1 , \forall x \in C\right\},$$
and the dual norm is defined as:
$$||z||_* = \text{sup} \left\{ z^Tx \mid ||x|| \leq 1\right\}.$$

But I cant see any connection between the definition. How can I show that the polar of the unit ball for a general norm $||\cdot||$ is the unit ball of the dual space? Where do I start from? Thanks.

Comment: The depth of your insight is not so clear from the question. Does it help that '$\| x \| \leq 1$' is the same as '$\forall x \in C$' in this context?

Comment: still unable to see the connection. How would you define the 'unit ball of the dual norm'?

Comment: In this context, the dual space of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is: $\mathbb{R}^n$ equipped with the norm $\| \cdot \|_*$. Hence, the unit ball of the dual space is $\{ z \in \mathbb{R}^n  \, | \,  \|z\|_* \leq 1 \}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B:=\{x\in\mathbf{R}^n:\|x\|\leq 1\}$.
We want to show that for the polar set defined as $B^\circ:=\{y\in\mathbf{R}^n:y^\top x\leq1,\,x\in B\}$, it holds that $B^\circ=\{y\in\mathbf{R}^n:\|y\|_*\leq 1\}$.
We will do so by showing that if $y\in B^\circ$, then $y\in \{y\in\mathbf{R}^n:\|y\|_*\leq 1\}$ and also the reverse.

($\subseteq$):
By definition, we have that
\begin{align}
B^\circ&:=\{y\in\mathbf{R}^n:y^\top x\leq1,\,x\in B\} = \{y\in\mathbf{R}^n:y^\top x\leq1,\,\|x\|\leq1\}.
\end{align}
Inspecting the last set, we have that for all $ y\in B^\circ$, it holds that
\begin{align}
y^\top x\leq1,\; \forall x:\|x\|\leq1.
\end{align}
Therefore, for any arbitrary $y\in B^\circ$, it must hold for the most extreme such $x$; that is, we can convert the "for all $x\in B$" condition into an optimization problem:
\begin{align}
\sup_x\{y^\top x :\|x\|\leq1\}\leq 1
\end{align}
but the LHS is $\|y\|_*$, so we see that $\|y\|_*\leq1$, meaning that $\|y\|_*\leq1,\;\forall y\in B^\circ$, since $y$ was arbitrary.
Thus we have that if $y\in B^\circ$, then $y\in \{y':\|y'\|_*\leq1\}$.

($\supseteq$):
On the other hand, if $y\in \{y':\|y'\|_*\leq1\}$, then
\begin{align}
\|y\|_*\leq1\iff\sup_x\{y^\top x :\|x\|\leq1\}\leq 1 \implies y\in B^\circ
\end{align}
by using the above argument but replacing the optimization problem in $x$ with the "for all $x$" quantifier.

Comment: I think your argument in $(\subseteq)$ is incorrect. E.g., $\sup_y\{y^\top x :\|x\|\leq1\}$ does not define the dual norm of $y$ (look at the subscript of sup). In fact, I think it can be directly derived from $y^\top x\leq1,\; \forall x:\|x\|\leq1$ that the dual of norm of $y$ is less than $1$.